# Nvim where do :mkview get saved on M1 Mac?

Tags: neovim, folding

My views are saving successfully. But I do not know where they get saved.

I looked here: `~/.config/nvim/`

and here: `~/.local/share/nvim`

But there is no `views` folder.

Where are views saved on M1 Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file of `:mkview` command, if used without a filename as argument, gets saved in the folder of `:h viewdir`.

From `:h :mkview`:

```
                                                        *:mkvie* *:mkview*
:mkvie[w][!] [file]     Write a Vim script that restores the contents of the
                        current window.
                        When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
                        When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a
                        name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.
```

To get the name of the `viewdir` folder, do this:

```
echo &viewdir
```

Comment: Thank you @Kadekai. It's in the `STATE` folder... not the `SHARE` folder. Thank you :)